# How do you make an image be the only visible part of a label?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

Here's some example code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root['background'] = 'black'

# this image here is just a placeholder. For the real application I will be using an image that is not a solid color.
image = tk.PhotoImage(width=1,height=1)
image.put(data='red', to=(0,0))
image = image.zoom(32, 32)

label = ttk.Label(root, image=image)
label.grid()

label = tk.Label(root, image=image)
label.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This code will put an image into a `Label` widget but the problem for me is that there is a border around the image as seen in this screenshot:

[image: label has a border around the image]

**How do you make an image be the only visible part of a label (i.e. you see only the image without border/padding)?**

Comment: Borders. There are borders.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `padx`, `pady` configuration parameters doesn't help.

For the tk.Label the solution is to change the `borderwidth`:

```
tk.Label(root, image=image, borderwidth=0)
```

For the ttk.Label you would have to create a custom style and set the ttk.Label()'s style with the custom style. I'm not sure how you would make the custom style for the ttk.Label.

Comment: Labels have a `highlightthickness` attribute which also needs to be set to zero. If you're wanting to remove all borders and _only_ show the image, there's no point in using the ttk label widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley re - "there's no point in using the ttk label widget": Are you saying this because if you only want to display the image... then you don't need any of the themeing/styling which is what the ttk.Label is for?

Comment: yes. The only value that the ttk widgets add is the theming and decoration, which in this case is being turned off.